# How to setup a failover server with KVM and DRBD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, failover, drbd

I have a server that I am virtualizing using the Virtualizor control panel. I need to set up a failover server that syncs everything on the first server to the second server. I am using DRBD to sync the servers. I have a couple of questions as I am new to this.

When using DRBD my understanding is that DRBD syncs partitions. In order to set this up should I sync just the KVMs or do I sync the partition that has the OS as well? If I make a configuration on server1 to the OS shouldn't I want that to sync to server2?

When using Virtualizor is it better practice to use Virtualizor on a separate server than where the KVMs are stored?

Comment: if you have two physical server and you are running a kvm virtual macchine on them, you could create a drbd copy on both server and put the vm there, to have a failover you could take a look to pacemaker